Python constrained optimization on external code
I am trying to wrap an external code in Python and then perform a constrained optimization on it. I think scipy.optimize should work, but I am unsure how to set up the constraints. My actual code cannot be shared but I think I can illustrate the problem without it.
Let's assume my external code is in this form:
def external_code(x):
    # does stuff with the x[0] through x[2] inputs
    # calculates all the outputs, y[0] through y[5]
    return y

Let's suppose my optimization objective is to minimize y[0] which is one of the things calculated in that external code, subject to a number of constraints. First, there are limits on acceptable values of the individual x inputs which I think I can handle like this: bounds = Bounds([0.0, -np.inf, 0.0], [10.0, 10.0, 2.0]). There are also constraints which must be respected for a valid optimum. Unlike the examples in the documentation or lecture examples I found, my constraints are on other outputs of the external code (i.e., y[1] through y[5]), not on a direct/simple combination of the x inputs. I think I need to set up a constraint function something like this:
def constraint_fcn(y):
    return np.array([5.0 - y[1],
                     1.0 - y[2],
                     1.0 - (y[3]+y[4]+y[5])
                    ])

I believe I would need to wrap my external code in an additional layer such that there is only one return value for the optimizer to operate on, i.e.,
def minimize_this(x):
    y = external_code(x)
    return y[0]

The call to the optimizer would then be something like:
x0 = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(minimize_this, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds,
                              constraints={'fun': constraint_fcn, 'type': 'ineq'})

The problem is that while minimize_this is set up to operate on x0 and each successive pick of x by the optimizer, constraint_fcn is not meant to work on x, but instead on those additional y values returned by the call to external_code. I could theoretically set up constraint_fcn to instead take in x, make its own call to external_code, and then set the limits based on the y[1] through y[5], but that would then mean that minimize_this and constraint_fcn are making separate calls to external_code which is not acceptable for computational performance reasons. I have seen in the documentation that both the function to be minimized and the constraint function can be passed additional arguments, but I was not seeing how to pass things from the function to me minimized to the constraint functions. I suspect that I just need to reformulate things, but I have been unable to find examples that are more like my setup.

This can be done with approximate memoisation.

@Reinderien - I'm not familiar with approximate memoisation, but based on getting the gist from a quick search just now, I think it ends up with the same kind of issue/question as brought up in the comments with the answer from jared, namely that I'm not sure how to deterministically know whether the calculations need to be done vs. being able to reuse the saved outputs. I can't have either the objective function or constraint function using stale data. If I'm just missing something in your suggestion, please add an answer with some additional detail about what you're proposing.

I think you'll be forced to evaluate your external function more. You can update your constraint_fcn to take x as an argument and get the y-values through the external function evaluation.
def constraint_fcn(x):
    y = external_code(x)
    return np.array([5.0 - y[1],
                     1.0 - y[2],
                     1.0 - (y[3]+y[4]+y[5])
                    ])


Edit: You may be able to cache your results using something like the functools.cache decorator.
import functools

@functools.cache
def cached_external(x):
    return external_code(x)

def minimize_this(x):
    return cached_external(x)[0]

def constraint_fcn(x):
    y = cached_external(x)
    return np.array([5.0 - y[1],
                     1.0 - y[2],
                     1.0 - (y[3]+y[4]+y[5])
                    ])

Since you're working with floats, you may need to write your own caching decorator that checks the result match within floating point precision.

Hmm...what you propose is the only thing I had been able to come up with, but that's terribly inefficient way of doing things for an expensive external_code. I was hoping I was missing a better way of handling it.

Yes, this will be very inefficient.

Do you know whether there is a deterministic order to the way the constraint function and function to be minimized are called? The calculation piece is expensive, but the output is written to a file. I should be able to run the calculations just once and read/parse the results file to get y from both minimize_this and from constraint_fcn, but I need to know where to put the call to do the actual calculations and be sure that those calculations are done before an attempt is made by either function to read the results file.

@Mike I'm not familiar enough with the underlying code to answer that. In the meantime, I edited my answer to mention how you might be able to use caching to avoid extra function calls.
